# Could not ping, broken pipe in MariaDB Drizzle JDBC

Tags: jdbc, ubuntu-12.04, mariadb, drizzle

I have an java application which uses **mariadb server**. From java, **drizzle jdbc** is used for connecting the mariadb server. Sometimes, I got an error, **broken pipe**.

I don't know why this error occured, its root cause.

Iam using ubuntu12.04, latest drizzle jdbc driver(1.2) and mariadb 5.5.29.

Please see the error log :

> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not ping: Broken
>   pipe at
>   org.drizzle.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.get(SQLExceptionMapper.java:97)
>   at
>   org.drizzle.jdbc.DrizzleConnection.isValid(DrizzleConnection.java:950)
>   at
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------  at
>   org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.concurrent.RequestMonitor$2.run(RequestMonitor.java:298)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:165)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:266)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) Caused by:
>   org.drizzle.jdbc.internal.common.QueryException: Could not ping:
>   Broken pipe at
>   org.drizzle.jdbc.internal.mysql.MySQLProtocol.ping(MySQLProtocol.java:424)
>   at
>   org.drizzle.jdbc.DrizzleConnection.isValid(DrizzleConnection.java:948)
>   ... 14 more Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe at
>   java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) at
>   java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
>   at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153) at
>   java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
>   at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
>   at
>   org.drizzle.jdbc.internal.mysql.packet.commands.MySQLPingPacket.send(MySQLPingPacket.java:47)
>   at
>   org.drizzle.jdbc.internal.mysql.MySQLProtocol.ping(MySQLProtocol.java:419)
>   ... 15 more

Could anyone help me on this ?

Comment: If this is a bug report, Drizzle JDBC project in git would be correct place to file it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above bug has been reported in github and fixed it : https://github.com/krummas/DrizzleJDBC/issues/17